# AWS CPP SDK: Pass AWSCredentials to S3Client

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-cpp

```
static const char* AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
static const char* AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "YYYYYYYYYY";
AWSCredentials credentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
```

The above code gives me an error of `incomplete type is not allowed` in visual studio and results ina  build error as `use of undefined type 'Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials'`

Please point me to correct way to construct a AWSCredentials object ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the header file of that class.
Also make sure you either use the fully qualified name of that class `Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials` or precede the declaration of that variable with a `using` statement `using namespace Aws::Auth;`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for those that still want to know:

I found the `AWSCredentials` class under `aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h`.

And as Marco said, you have to use `Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials`.